# Xamarin.Android - typeof and GetType always return System.RuntimeType

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, reflection, types

I am developing a Xamarin.Android WebView application, and in an attempt to use Reflection to implement some AJAX methods, I have noticed that both `Object.GetType` and `typeof` always return `System.RuntimeType`.

This happens regardless of what I pass to them - it happens when I pass `string`, `int`, `MyClass`, etc to typeof, as well as when I call GetType on instances of these classes.

Minimum runnable code is trivial:

```
private class HybridWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public static type Test() {
        Log.Debug("TypeDebug", typeof(string));
        Log.Debug("TypeDebug", typeof(bool));
        Log.Debug("TypeDebug", typeof(MyClass));
        Log.Debug("TypeDebug", "test".GetType());
        Log.Debug("TypeDebug", (34).GetType());
        Log.Debug("TypeDebug", (new MyClass()).GetType());
    }
}
```

All of the above print "System.RuntimeType". The equivalent code compiled using .NET prints the expected values - System.String, System.Bool, etc.

Has anyone else using Xamarin.Android encountered this? If so, is there a workaround? It is making the use of Reflection impossible for me, and I need it to pass information between JavaScript running in the WebView and the app itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Android.Util.Log.Debug/Info/...` expects a `string` as the 2nd param, so I'm not sure how your code is even compiling...

You should be outputting a string representation of the type:

```
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", typeof(string).FullName);
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", typeof(bool).FullName);
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", "test".GetType().FullName);
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", (34).GetType().FullName);
```

or

```
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", $"{typeof(string)}");
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", $"{typeof(bool)}");
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", $"{"test".GetType()}");
Log.Debug("TypeDebug", $"{(34).GetType()}");
```

Output:

```
02-21 20:38:29.101  4243  4243 D TypeDebug: System.String
02-21 20:38:29.101  4243  4243 D TypeDebug: System.Boolean
02-21 20:38:29.101  4243  4243 D TypeDebug: System.String
02-21 20:38:29.101  4243  4243 D TypeDebug: System.Int32
```